# JS - Object expected on new object();

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am i doing wrong here?

```
    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByTagName("li");
    var hover;
    var moname;
    var slider;
    var newPos=new Object();
    var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    for (x in navbar) {
        if (x != 'length') {
            moname=(x+"-mo");
            hover=document.createElement("div");
            hover.setAttribute('id','slider');
            hover.setAttribute('name',moname);
         body.appendChild(hover);
            newPos.left=Posleft(x);
            newPos.top=PosTop(x);
            $('div.[name=moname]').offset(newPos);
        }
    }
```

Every time it gets to

```
newPos.top=PosTop(x);
```

It stops at newPos and says object expected.
newPos is a new object though

Comment: What is `PosTop`? You sure it's not `Postop`?

Comment: .....well ive just made a complete fool of myself, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your functions are named correctly, I think `PosTop` is a typo there since `Posleft` is lower-case and it's now blowing up on the line before.  Always check the casing to make sure that the right-hand side of the operation is defined as well :)

Comment: @Diesal11 - welcome :) just leaving an answer here for the next person, you're not first to do this...*not even close*, but others searching for this same error just may get help out of your question :)